# Some misunderstanding about sort extensions

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have the following code example:

```
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(5);
    list.Add(6);
    list.Add(7);

  list.OrderByDescending(n=>n).Reverse();
```

But when I use this:

```
list.OrderByDescending(n=>n).Reverse();
```

I don't get wanted result.

If instead of the above statement, I use this one:

```
list.Reverse();
```

I get the wanted result.

Any idea why I don't get wanted result using the first statement ?

I believe I am missing something in understanding the extensions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What result do you expect? '1..7' or '7..1'? If the answer is 'all the numbers from seven to one' then just use list.OrderByDescending(a => a);

Comment: You should write a.) what you expect and b.) what you get.

Comment: If the original list looks like this 1...7 
I want the result to be like this 7...1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: So the problem seems to be that you think that the `Enumerable` extensions would change the original collection. No they do not. Actually they return something new you need to asign to a variable:

```
IEnumerable<int> ordered = list.OrderByDescending(n => n);
foreach(int i in ordered)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

---

`OrderByDescending` orders descending(highest first) which is what you obviously want. So i don't understand why you reverse it afterwards.

So this should give you the expected result:

```
var ordered = list.OrderByDescending(n=> n);
```

This returns an "arbitrary" order:

```
list.Reverse()
```

since it just reverses the order you have added  the `int`s. If you have added them in an ordered way you don't need to order at all.

In general: use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` if you want to order a sequence and `Reverse` if you want to invert the sequence what is not necessarily an order (it is at least confusing).

Answer (score 6):

The [`list.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) method reverses the list in-place, so your original `list` is changed.

The `.OrderByDescending()` extension method produces a new list (or rather an `IEnumerable<T>`) and leaves your original `list` intact.

**EDIT**
To get two lists, for both sort orders:

```
List<int> upList = list.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
List<int> downList = list.OrderByDescending(n => n).ToList();
```

Comment: +! - I missed the in-place/new list aspect!

Comment: I need to get to lists.The first is ordered by descending  and the second is OrderByIncreasing(with the same value,that is why I using the reverse)